# How copy all subfolders with the name "test results" in a directory, using msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I want to copy all the subfolders a directory with the name "Testresults".

I have tried Include="..\Test**\Testresults*.*"

```
<FilesToCopy Include="C:Test\**\Testresults\*.*"/>
```

all the subfolders in Test with name "Testresults" should be copied to the output folder

Comment: Did you mean C:\Test instead of C:Test?

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to copy all files from the `Testresults` subfolders to output folder. You can add this script into your xx.csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FilesToCopy Include="C:\Test\**\Testresults\*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyFiles" AfterTargets="build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)"
    DestinationFolder="$(OutPutPath)"  />
  </Target>
```

Since I use `AfterTargets="build"`, this copy target will execute after every successful build. If you want to execute the copy operation before build process, you can use  `BeforeTargets="build"`.

And if you want to copy all files from `Testresults` folders under `C:Test\` to the `Testresults` folder in output folder(`bin\debug or bin\release`), you can set the `DestinationFolder` in this way: `DestinationFolder="$(OutPutPath)\Testresults"`. Hope it helps :)